# Google Datastore DataSet not updating correctly

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use Google Clouds DataStore with nodejs. I was under the impression that the update method would only update the values that you pass along.  In the below example the update method completely overrides the entire object in the datastore and does not just update the isDraft value.

```
// Save data to your dataset.
var blogPostData = {
    title: 'How to make the perfect homemade pasta',
    author: 'Andrew Chilton',
    isDraft: true
};
var blogPostKey = dataset.key(['BlogPost', 123]);
dataset.save({
    key: blogPostKey,
    data: blogPostData
}, function (err) {
    console.log(blogPostKey);
    // `blogPostKey` has been updated with an ID so you can do more operations
    // with it, such as an update:
    setTimeout(function () {
        dataset.save({
            key: blogPostKey,
            data:{
                isDraft: false
            }
        }, function (err) {
            if (!err) {
            }
        });
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Datastore does not support partial updates: when updating an entity, one needs to send the full entity to write. This is indicated in [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Updating_an_entity): _The object data overwrites the existing entity. The entire object is sent to Datastore._

Comment: @Clément Ok. I was using an example found at the gcloud node github repository. And their example is strongly hinting that it would just update. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/tree/v0.19.0

Comment: I believe this is an issue with the documentation, I opened https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/812